# There is an incorrect(?) tag "thelegobatmanmovie" which prevents me from creating the correct(?) "the-lego-batman-movie" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There is an incorrect(?) tag [thelegobatmanmovie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thelegobatmanmovie) which prevents me from creating the correct(?) [the-lego-batman-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lego-batman-movie) tag.

How should this be handled?

Comment: I agree - the second tag looks better. The should be merged and synonimised.

Comment: What's funny is that I got the whole "you can't create tags on the mobile website" error and so when I went to retry on full browser it *had* created it. I completely spaced it at the time, so thanks for the catch.

Comment: Yes, I don't think Thele Gobat Man is relevant.

Answer (score 12):

It's done, I've renamed the tags.

Comment: "the-" could be cut off IMO,